# Jekyll Can't Get Post Image to Show on Post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

On my front matter, I have:

image: SNKRS.jpeg

On my post layout, I have:

```
---
layout: "wrapper"
---

<section class="postlayout">
      <div class="postsummary">
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ page.description }}</p>
        {% if post.image %}
          <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/blogimages/{{ post.image }}" alt="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.title }}"">
        {% endif %}
      </div>
</section>
<section class="postbody">
  {{content}}
  {% include lazyload.html %}
</section>
```

But on the post, the image isn't being pulled. It only pulls if I have a {% for post in site.posts %} around the code. But when I use that, it pulls all the posts on the website instead of just the current post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to get the image from the Front Matter of the post, this code may help you.

Layout post file: `..\_layouts\post.html`

```html
<section class="postlayout">
  <div class="postsummary">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ page.description }}</p>
    {% if page.image %}
      <img src="{{ page.image }}" alt="{{ page.title }}"">
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</section>
```

**NOTE**: remember to add this information to the post's Front Matter.

Markdown post file: `2020-05-12-my-post.md`

```yaml
---
title: "I'm the title of Post."
description: "I'm the description of the post."
image: /assets/blogimages/name_of_image.jpg
---
```

**TO BETTER UNDERSTAND (added after replying).**

Why am I using `page.image` rather than `post.image`?

Because, in the example posted in your question, you are treating the `.html` or `.md` file as a page, rather than as a post.

The variable `page`, of `page.image`, is an official Jekyll variable.
While the variable `post`, of `post.image`, is not an official Jekyll variable so it does not exist unless explicitly declared
(here more info: [Jekyll Variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/))

Read below to understand.

If you use the variable `page.image` Jekyll takes the content present in the variable `image` from the Front Matter of the page (by default a page is a file `page-name.html` contained in the root directory of the Jekyll project). Note that here the `.html` file is therefore treated as a page. You can also create a page using the `page-name.md` file so as to use the advantages of the MarkDown syntax, but then you should associate it with a layout that could be `blog.html` appropriately placed in the `_layout` directory.

If you want to treat a `YY-MM-DD-post-name.md` file as a post, you must first insert the file in the `_posts` directory of the Jekyll project. Then you will have to create a page (or layout), for example `blog.html` with the code that goes to list all the existing posts. To do this you need to create a loop that iterates every `.md` file in the `_posts` folder.

The following code is a typical example:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <h2><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <img src="{{ post.image }}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In the second line the variable `post` will contain the values ​​present in the Front Matter of each single post. From here we understand that `site.posts` is treated as an `array` and we need the `for` loop to access every single element of the `array` .

So using the `for` loop we can access the title of the post via `post.title` variable or the image via `post.image` variable.

Without using the `for` loop, we could also access the values ​​of the `array` by specifying the position of each element in the `array`, as in the following example:

```
<h2>{{ site.posts[0].title }}</h2>
<img src="{{ site.posts[0].image }}" >
```

With the example above we access the elements in position 0 of the `array` but it is obviously a useless method that does not exploit the power of the `for` loop.

More info here: [Jekyll List posts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/08-blogging/#list-posts)

Comment: This worked.. I had to change everything to page.image not post.image. Any idea why it's page and not post?

Comment: Because in reality you are treating the file as a page and not as a post. I edited my answer to make you understand better.